# I need to integrate an external system with Salesforce using webhooks

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

The external system (Checkfront) allows me to create webhooks and I must provide a secure URL to POST notification data to. It can post the data in JSON or XML

What URL should I post the data to? I will eventually need to read this post from salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two basic parts to the exercise: 1) Design your web service in a such a way to be able to handle and parse the specific incoming payload "webhook", and 2) Expose it via public Force.com site

I answered a similar post here, this should help:
[Creation of a Public API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64253/creation-of-a-public-api/64260#64260)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else reading this and looking for a more "dynamic solution", I've put together a plugin for Salesforce Visual Workflow which works with any HTTPS endpoint to POST JSON data. Saves writing APEX code or custom triggers.

[SFDC Any Object to POST HTTPS JSON Webook](http://moometric.com/integrations/sf/salesforce-visual-workflow-plugin-post-json-callout-external-webservice/)